# SELECT FOUND_ROWS() not working with PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I changed my code to finally using PDO instead of mysql_..

I changed the code of one of my query which is like

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * ....etc
```

but now my code

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

and the array

```
echo $array[0]['FOUND_ROWS()']
```

return value = 0;

there is anything I should know about PDO and this type of queries?

Comment: What is `var_dump($array)`? Also normaly I would set an alias to the `FOUND_ROWS()`.

Comment: You need to show your actual PHP code, as the execution sequence is important.